# Remove a specific JSONObject from JSONArray in groovy

Tags: json, grails, groovy, hashmap, jsonslurper

Say I have a JSON request payload like

```
{
    "workflow": {
        "approvalStore": {
            "sessionInfo": {
                "user": "baduser"
            },
            "guardType": "Transaction"
        }
    }
}
```

I get the value of `user` via

```
def user = req.get("workflow").get("approvalStore").get("sessionInfo").get("user")
```

Now, I get a RestResponse `approvalList` which I store as `list` and return to caller as `return approvalList.json as JSON`. All well so far.

Suppose the response (`approvalList.json`) looks like below JSONArray -

```
[
    {
        "objId": "abc2",
        "maker": "baduser"
    },
    {
        "objId": "abc1",
        "maker": "baduser"
    },
    {
        "objId": "abc4",
        "maker": "gooduser"
    }
]
```

[image]

**Question** : How may I filter the approvalList.json so that it doesn't contain entries (objects) that have `"maker": "baduser"` ? The value passed to `maker` should essentially be the `user` variable I got earlier.

Ideal required output -

[image]

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear if you always want a single object returned or a list of objects but using `collect` is going to be the key here:

```
// given this list
List approvalList  = [
    [objId: "abc2", maker: "baduser"], 
    [objId: "abc1", maker: "baduser"], 
    [objId: "abc4", maker: "gooduser"]
]

// you mentioned you wanted to match a specific user
String user = "baduser"
List filteredList = approvalList.findAll{ it.maker != user}​​​​​​

// wasn't sure if you wanted a single object or a list...
if (filteredList.size() == 1) {
    return filteredList[0] as JSON
} else {
    return filteredList as JSON
}​
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted a list of objects that didn't have `maker=baduser` mapping.

Comment: Then I think you may want to replace `approvalList.findAll{ it.maker == user}​​​​​​` with `approvalList.findAll{ it.maker != 'baduser'}​​​​​​`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple. First parse the JSON into an object, then walk through and test.

```
JSONObject json = JSON.parse(text)
json.each(){ it ->
   it.each(){ k,v ->
      if(v=='baduser'){
          // throw exception or something
      } 
   }
}
```